# Delete the country from address of LatLng object

Tags: java, android

i used LatLng object and i do not need the country section in my addresses.

this is my function that return the myLatLng:

```
   public static Address getAdrressFromLatLng(Context context, LatLng latLng){
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    try{
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
        return addresses.get(0);
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("LatLng", "geoLocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }catch(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
        Log.e("LatLng", "geoLocate: bad Latlang: ");
    }
    return null;
}
```

and than i`m doing:

```
 Address jobAdress = LatLng.getAdrressFromLatLng(this, myLatLng)
```

and print:

```
jobAdress.getAddressLine(0)
```

but the result is with the country and i want to remove it in an elegant way.

possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be difficult to remove the country in a consistent way, because the exact form of the address string might vary depending on the addresss.  Instead, you may try building the address piece by piece using other getter methods:

```
Address jobAddress = LatLng.getAdrressFromLatLng(this, myLatLng);
StringBuilder address = new StringBuilder("");

address.append(jobAddress.getThoroughfare()).append(", ");  // 740 Park Avenue
address.append(jobAddress.getLocality()).append(", ");      // New York
address.append(jobAddress.getPostalCode());                 // 10021
```

This might output something along the lines of:

```
740 Park Avenue, New York, 10021
```

You may check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address) for more information.